# Chances to refute : Mersenne numbers with prime exponents are squarefree$\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose, a third Wieferich prime will be found.

> Can we estimate the chance that this new Wieferich-prime will refute the conjecture that a Mersenne number $\ 2^q-1\ $ with $\ q\ $ prime is always squarefree ?

It is well known that $\ p^2\mid 2^q-1\ $ with primes $\ p,q\ $ implies that $\ p\ $ must be a Wieferich prime and that the two known Wieferich primes cannot satisfy $\ p^2\mid 2^q-1\ $.

If $\ p^2\mid 2^q-1\ $ , then the order of $\ 2\ $ modulo $\ p^2\ $ must be $\ q\ $.

Hence a third Wieferich prime $\ p\ $ would refute the above conjecture if and only if the order of $\ 2\ $ modulo $\ p^2\ $ is a prime number , which is not the case for the known Wieferich-primes. What is the chance this is the case , if the third Wieferich prime has , lets say , $\ 20\ $ digits ?

Also : How is the situation in the case of Fermat-numbers ? Can we hope that a third Wieferich prime will refute that Fermat-numbers are always squarefree ?

Comment: Don't add additional parts of the question to comments - add it to the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Done

Comment: >This also implies that Wieferich primes can be defined as primes $p$ such that the multiplicative orders of 2 modulo $p$ and modulo $p^2$ coincide           -wikipedia

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter would give a reason for the downvote.

Comment: @JOSEARNALDOBEBITADRIS Thank you for your interest. I do not understand what you mean with a table. If $p$ is a prime such that $p^2$ divides $2^q-1$ for some prime $q$ or some fermat number, then $p$ is a Wieferich prime different from the two known Wieferich primes. So, $2^q-1$ with prime $q$ and the Fermat numbers have very little chance to be non-squarefree.

Comment: @Peter Ahh now I understand.  That is because we have not yet discovered another Wieferich prime!

Comment: @Peter Any way, I have deleted my earlier comment, as I have just realized how dumb it was!  =)